# Changelog handling in semantic-release?

Tags: github, git-flow, changelog, semantic-release

Using [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) in our Github workflows.

They are setup like this:

```
[
  {name: 'main', prerelease: false},
  {name: 'staging', prerelease: true},
  {name: 'development', prerelease: true}
]
```

Pushes to `development` are deployed to `development` environment, `staging` to `staging` etc.

Now with the package above every time the version is bumped, `semantic-release` creates a changelog using [semantic-release/changelog](https://github.com/semantic-release/changelog).

How should we handle the conflicting changelogs in the different branches now?

1. Option: Only enable changelog creation on `release` branches. (I don't know how. Plugin has no such option.)
2. Option: Automatically merge back the changelog into the 'hierarchically' lower branch. E.g. `staging` back into `development`.

I am wondering is there anyone out there with a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I see people upvoting this question. I opened a PR with `semantic-release/changelog` to allow the use of templating in the `CHANGELOG.md` filename. This way at least you could have different changelogs for different branches. There has been 0 activity from the maintainers though. Soon its gonna be open for a year...

Here is the PR: https://github.com/semantic-release/changelog/pull/106.

Comment: https://github.com/semantic-release/changelog/pull/106#issuecomment-891686740: "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch": Don't forget to rebase your PR branch on top of upstream(semantic-release)/master, and force push your PR branch again.

Comment: @VonC, yeah not gonna do anything until a contributor makes a comment in the PR. Otherwise I'll be rebasing for the next year.